# How to add data to the DataGrid in every time when button pressed in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I my WPF application there are two textboxes and one DataGrid. There is a button called "Add". I want to add data which hold in textboxes to the DataGrid every time I press the button. In my code first time only update the DataGrid. How i can fix this.

XAML

```
  <TextBox x:Name="txt_description" Margin="0,10,20,15"/>
  <TextBox x:Name="txt_quantity" Margin="0,10,20,15" PreviewKeyDown="txt_quantity_PreviewKeyDown"/>
  <Button x:Name="btn_Add" Margin="0,0,0,15" Content="Add" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="100" Click="btn_Add_Click" />
<DataGrid x:Name="dgd_items" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="16"/>
```

C#

```
 private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsDto obj = new ItemsDto();
        obj.ItemCode = cmb_ItemCode.SelectedItem.ToString();
        obj.descripition = txt_description.Text;
        obj.qty = Convert.ToInt32(txt_quantity.Text);

        Dto.Add(obj);

        dgd_items.ItemsSource = Dto;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on how to do that:

1. XAML

   ```
   <Window x:Class="SolutionDatagrid.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
       <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <DataGrid x:Name="dgCustomers" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" Grid.Column="0"></DataGrid>
           <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
               <TextBlock Margin="10" FontWeight="Bold">Customer Information:</TextBlock>

               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                   <TextBlock>First Name</TextBlock>
                   <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName"/>
               </StackPanel>

               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                   <TextBlock>Last Name</TextBlock>
                   <TextBox x:Name="txtLastName"/>
               </StackPanel>

               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                   <TextBlock>Favourite Color</TextBlock>
                   <ComboBox x:Name="cbxColor" ItemsSource="{Binding Colours}"/>
               </StackPanel>

               <TextBlock Margin="10" FontWeight="Bold">Actions:</TextBlock>
               <Button Margin="10" Height="50" Click="Button_Add_Click">Add Data</Button>
               <Button Margin="10" Height="50" Click="Button_Reset_Click">Reset</Button>
           </StackPanel>
       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```
2. CODE

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;
   using System.Windows.Data;
   using System.Windows.Documents;
   using System.Windows.Input;
   using System.Windows.Media;
   using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
   using System.Windows.Navigation;
   using System.Windows.Shapes;

   namespace SolutionDatagrid
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
       /// </summary>
       public partial class MainWindow : Window
       {
           public MainWindow()
           {
               this.InitializeComponent();

               // List of Customers
               this.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

               // List of Colours
               this.Colours = new List<string>
               {
                   "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet"
               };

               this.DataContext = this;
           }

           // Properties
           public List<string> Colours { get; set; }
           public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }


           // Button Click Events
           private void Button_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               // Variables to hold customer data
               string firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
               string lastName = txtLastName.Text;
               string colour = cbxColor.SelectedItem.ToString();

               // If our data is valid
               if(firstName !=null && lastName!=null && colour!=null)
               {
                   // Create new customer using data
                   Customer customer = new Customer { Name = firstName, Surname = lastName, Colour = colour };

                   // Add the new cutomer to the existing list of customers
                   this.Customers.Add(customer);
               }
           }

           private void Button_Reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               this.Customers.Clear();
           }
       }

       // Customer Class
       public class Customer
       {
           // Properties
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public string Surname { get; set; }
           public string Colour { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```

   3. SCREEN SHOT

Simple WPF  DataGrid & Data Binding Example:

[image]